# Bypassing SSL in HTTPS PUT request in Angular2

Tags: android, angular, http, ssl, ionic2

I wanted to test API request on the mobile version of my app (Ionic2). On the desktop it works fine - I used Postman, disabled SSL verification and made a request to the unsecured HTTPS site (without a certificate). Is there any way to test it on the Android device? I'm still waiting for the certificate but would like to confirm that it works and I get right response.

Code is probably unnecessary but here it is:

```
this.http.put(this.server, body, {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("RESPONSE: ", JSON.stringify(data));
    })
```

In the console I get PUT `https://example.com/xxx net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` and `Uncaught Response with status: 0 for URL: null`

Comment: I think youre going to need to create a self signed certificate, and host your app using it.

Comment: @cgatian how can I do it?